# Purpose of docker container for react app in production

Tags: reactjs, docker

I just started to dive deeper into Docker and saw interesting example of wrapping React app into docker container for production (and there are a lot such examples on internet) with (IMHO) not very "elegant" implementation. I can explain its dockerization by working in team / having the same environment over team members for development.

However, what is not clear for me (and I couldn't find this anywhere) - if the result product of react application (npm run build) is an "optimized for production" package containing html, css, js and other resources... **What is the value of docker there?** Is it done for the sake of running everything through docker or there is an actual reasoning here that I'm missing?

Any thoughts will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: A guess off the top of my head would be to open up your deployment options, e.g. to kubernetes

Comment: I've seen some effective uses of multi-stage builds that create an Nginx-based deployable with production-ready static files.  I've seen some ineffective uses to work around difficulties installing Node directly on the host.  In my day job, front-end applications are built using containers as part of our CI system, but then just deployed as static files via a file-hosting service, without a container specifically involved.